# php - dealing with multi-dimensional arrays with different inner array lengths

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an array of id's that are associated with names that I would like to process with a foreach loop but I get an error that says: Undefined offset: n.

I get that it is because the inner arrays are different lengths, so how do I get around this? I want to gather each name and query them to my database in one function or loop

```
Array
( 
[id_1] => Array
    (
        [0] => "Jim"
    )

[id_2] => Array
    (
        [0] => "John"
        [1] => "Mike"
        [2] => "Mary"

    )

[id_3] => Array
    (
        [0] => "Elizabeth"
        [1] => "Ashley"
    )
)
```

The query i'd like to run is "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = `id` AND name = `name`"

the foreach loop i'm using is:

```
$count = 0;
foreach ($myArray as $key => $value) {
    echo $key . ": " . $value[$count] . '<br>';
    $count++;

}
```

Comment: Show your code with `foreach`

Comment: Please also add the query you want to use the names in for clarification.

Comment: *"I would like to process with a foreach loop but I get an error that says: Undefined offset: n."* -- where is the `foreach` loop?

Comment: Flatten the array to a one dimensional array?

Comment: _“process with a foreach loop but I get an error that says: Undefined offset: n”_ - why would you be using an offset (vulgo: index, key) with a _foreach_ loop to begin with? Sounds like you are still trying to access elements by their key directly? That kinda negates the purpose behind a foreach loop, which easily allows you to loop over data sets of unknown length (or with not even numeric/consecutive keys.)

Comment: @CBroe he is probably foreach ['id_2'] and use the key to get values from id_1 and 3.

Comment: `var_dump(array_merge(...array_values($myArray)));`

Answer (score 0):

By using PHP implode to join the names values and using IN in your MySQL WHERE clause:

```
// Test array
$myArray = array(
    "id_1" => array("Jim"),
    "id_2" => array(
        "John",
        "Mike",
        "Mary"
    ),
    "id_3" => array(
        "Elizabeth",
        "Ashley"
    )
);

foreach($myArray as $id => $names) {
    // Prepare the MySql statement.
    $sqlStr = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ";
    $sqlStr .= "id = '" . $id . "' ";
    $sqlStr .= "AND name IN ('" . implode("', '", $names) . "')";

    // Execute the query here..
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly!

Comment: Give a thumbs up! :D